# sched_setscheduler returns "Operation not permitted", as root, with setcap cap_sys_nice=ep, with limits.conf configured, etc

Tags: linux, real-time, scheduler

I am trying (but failing) to get a program to run with realtime priority (SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR).

Here are the things I have done to try to achieve this:

- I'm running the program as root.
- I put "* - rtprio 99" into "/etc/security/limits.conf" and rebooted ("ulimit -r" now reports 99).
- I ran "setcap cap_sys_nice=ep" on my binary. (I also tried "cap_sys_nice=eip", "cap_sys_nice+ep", and "cap_sys_nice+eip".)

Here's the code I'm using to set the scheduling priority:

```
int set_priority()
{
    struct sched_param param;
    memset(&param, 0, sizeof(struct sched_param));
    int policy = SCHED_RR;
    int max_priority = sched_get_priority_max(policy);
    param.sched_priority = 1; //max_priority;
    printf("max_priority=%d\n", max_priority);
    if (sched_setscheduler(0, policy, &param) == -1) {
        perror("sched_setscheduler");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've been spending a few days poking at this problem, but none of the solutions I find work. No matter what, sched_setscheduler always throws an "Operation not permitted" error.

BTW, I have also verified that the kernel I'm running does have realtime support by checking /proc/config.gz and /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us.

Any help you could provide would be very much appreciated!

Environment:

```
Linux zmnano0 5.10.104-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Mar 19 07:55:28 PDT 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Minor addenda:

- Actually, when I run as root (having started a shell by "sudo su -"), "ulimit -r" returns 0 for root while having returned 99 for the regular user.
- It doesn't matter if I run my program from the root shell or as a regular user using sudo. "Operation not permitted" is always the error.